# SQL select units with condition of another column

Tags: sql

I have this

| ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | A |
| 001 | B |
| 001 | C |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | A |
| 002 | D |
| 003 | G |
| 003 | D |
| 003 | C |
| 004 | G |
| 004 | D |
| 004 | R |

and I wand ID list if they don't have product C...so:

002

Comment: * so I want list with ID 002 and ID 004

Comment: Please tag your DBMS also.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the set difference between all ids and all ids with a "*c*" with the standard way of doing it: using the `NOT IN` operator in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM tab
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM tab WHERE Product = 'C')
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(product = 'C') OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS cnt_C
    FROM sample_table
) WHERE cnt_C = 0
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this, but I think a very readable way is to use `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM mytable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.Product = 'C')
```

The `WHERE` clause checks that there is no row with product C and the same id. The `DISTINCT` ensures you don't get multiples of the same id returned.

Comment: This solution won't work as long as the subquery contains a reference to a table ("*t1*") which is not explicitly referenced in the scope of the subquery itself.

Comment: @lemon In what DBMS would this fail?

Comment: There are lots of DBMS's out there, but I'm pretty sure this won't work for the most common databases, including Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, PostgreSQL.

Comment: @lemon I tested in Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, and PostgreSQL (see Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9212983768d5cf9e21b064e549b64b5b ) and it works fine in all.

Comment: @lemon I think `EXISTS` would be completely useless if it couldn't reference the outer query.

Comment: This feels really awkward for me to see, but it's rather interesting to know. I guess this works only with the `EXISTS`.

Comment: @lemon Unfortunately I don't know the specific limitations, but I think there are many scenarios where a subquery can reference tables in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you just need a normal where

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE product != product_name`

*insert the table name in the place of Table_name and product name in the place of product_name

Comment: This solution will work only for IDs that have "C" products only. If an "*ID*" is associated to both a "*C*" and a "*B*" product, this ID will be wrongly returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
     id
from
     your_table_name
where
     product <> 'C';
```

This will return you list of ID's that don't have product C

Comment: This solution will work only for IDs that have "C" products only. If an "*ID*" is associated to both a "*C*" and a "*B*" product, this ID will be wrongly returned.